# How to fetch audio from my api with protected urls using just_audio (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I'm trying to play audios using just_audio on my flutter app. My audio url are coming from an API that i've build using django rest framework and the urls to those audios are protected (I'm using token authorization)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a token (e.g. obtained by making a separate [HTTP request](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/httpserver) to another REST API you provided), you would normally pass that token in the `Authorization` header when requesting the audio file from your server.

Every method in just_audio that loads a URL also takes a `headers` parameter so that you can do just that.

Approach 1:

```dart
await player.setUrl(url,
    headers: {'Authorization': yourHeaderValue});
```

Approach 2:

```dart
await player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {'Authorization': yourHeaderValue});
```

Where `yourHeaderValue` is the Authorization header value required by your REST API. E.g.

```
Token 481594aa8B.....
```